# How to fix relative path issue in Joomla for a component?

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have created one component in Joomla and added one view called 'editor' inside it

```
component name: com_at
view name: editor
layout name: default.php
```

After that, I have added 'content-editor' folder on path: /var/www/dev.com/public/content-editor

content-editor contain following file and folder(it's a javascript application with no php dependency, I want to wrap this application inside Joomla and only authenticated users should be able to access it)

- index.html
- styles

code in index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/external.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  text
</body>
</html>
```

Now in default.php (a layout file which is inside 'editor' view) I have added following code

```
<?php
require_once "content-editor/index.html"
?>
```

When I'm loading view it's giving 404 for external.min.css & style.min.css as it looking to find file http://dev.com/styles/external.min.css/

I want it to find this file http://dev.com/content-editor/styles/external.min.css

If I change CSS path in href to "content-editor/styles/external.min.css" then it is working fine but I don't want to make changes in index.html

Comment: I have tried using base tag, but I guess Joomla is adding one base tag by default, thus it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have three options here:

- adjust the index.html file
- load the content of the file and do a search&replace of the path instead of directly using it.
- implement this integration in the right way. Joomla provides some editor plugins out of the box where you can check how to implement your integration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to modify the links like

```
./styles/external.min.css
./styles/style.min.css
```